# Why not use early binding when possible?

Tags: c++, late-binding

I read an example about polymorphism which looks like bellow, where show() is a virtual function:

```
int main()
{
  Derived dv1;
  Derived dv2;
  Base* ptr;

  ptr = &dv1;
  ptr->show();

  ptr = &dv2;
  ptr->show();
}
```

The books say that in this case, the compiler will use `late binding` technique. I do understand the difference between late binding and early binding. However, in this example, we (and maybe the compiler as well) can see that which function should be called because there's no change in the objects that `ptr` points to. So why not early binding in this case because late binding will cause some overhead?

Comment: How do you know your compiler doesn't actually detect that case and does some optimization for it? Have you checked the generated assembler code? With optimizations enabled?

Comment: I am not familiar with assembler code. The fact that the books say late binding is applied in this case makes me confused.

Comment: clang at least seems to do [a *bit* more](https://godbolt.org/g/9pnkg9) than just optimize the calls to be to derived, at least for simple implementations of `show`.

Comment: The books present the rule. Compilers may optimize the exception to the rule when the program remains semantically the same.

Comment: So I guess I got the answer. Thanks very much.

Comment: @jaggedSpire that is insane optimization!

Comment: @jaggedSpire try returning a string or something like that.

Comment: @DanielA.White yeah, it doesn't tend to optimize types requiring dynamic allocation *nearly* as well, though of course [c-style strings are fair game](https://godbolt.org/g/sKpmVd).

Comment: As far as I know, if the compiler doesn't know the implementation of the virtual functions, it will only try to "devirtualize" the first function call when it knows the concrete type (ie: like in OP's example). The reason for that is that the function call might change the dynamic type of an object through some language hacks (ex: placement `new` on `this`). I think there are compiler switches to make the compiler assume you never do that, though

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> However, in this example, we (and maybe the compiler as well) can see that which function should be called because there's no change in the objects that ptr points to.

Correct.

> So why not early binding in this case because late binding will cause some overhead?

The function is called through a pointer to a polymorphic type, so late binding is used.

Late binding simply means that the call will resolve to the most derived override (down to the concrete type of the object) - rather than resolving the call to `Base::show`.

Sure, dynamic dispatch may be needed for late binding in general, but the implementation is allowed to break the rules, if the program still behaves the same as if it had followed the rules. This is known as the [*as-if*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) rule. And due to the observation that you also made, changing the program to do static dispatch does not change the behaviour, so compiler is allowed to optimize and avoid doing dynamic dispatch.

Comment: This technique is called _devirtualization_. You can read about GCC implementation in [series of blog posts](http://hubicka.blogspot.ru/2014/01/devirtualization-in-c-part-1.html)